# How do I change the launcher icon back to default after using WhiteSur user theme?

Tags: gnome, icons, 22.04, themes

I installed the WhiteSur user theme from GitHub (https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme), and decided I wanted to uninstall. I went through the uninstallation steps, and everything went back to the default theme (Yaru) except for the launcher icon in the Ubuntu dock. I do not know where Ubuntu retrieves the icon image file from, or how to set it back to default. I have tried disabling dash-to-dock, and the icon stayed the same.

Thanks in advance,

-Slack

Comment: We can assume that since removing the theme you also have rebooted? Temporarily create a new account and see if it happens there. Probably not, so that will confirm it is an issue in your user's configuration only.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted. The problem is not present in an alternate account. I assume it's a problem with the uninstall script. All I need to do is find where the png/svg (idk) is located, then I can replace it with the default.

Comment: So you know to look under your own account. Look for an icon with a name 'view-grid*' and/or 'view-app-grid*' in your home folder (hidden folders). Delete the file, and depending on which folder it is, it may be better to delete the entire folder where the icon resides.

Comment: I could not find it in the home directory, so I ran Nautilus as root and searched /. No conclusive results.